# What's the difference between the singular and plural form of "affection"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

[This OALD page](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/affection?q=affection) suggests that *affection* has two, but very close, meaning based on the plural form:

- *affection*: the feeling of liking or loving somebody/something very much and caring about them
- *affection****s***: a person’s feelings of love

What exactly is the difference between them? To me they're all synonyms of *love*.

Comment: I think it's misleading to suggest that those two definitions themselves are somehow "different". The two plural examples *Anne had two men trying to win her **affections**, 
The object of her **affections** was a young man named Paul* would both be fine (and mean *exactly* the same thing) with singular ***affection***. Personally, I'd say that ***affections*** is something of a poetic / literary ***affectation*** - it's just that we can't use plural in contexts like OAld's earlier (singular) example: *Children need lots of love and **affection*** (where ***affections*** is non-idiomatic).

Comment: (That's to say - it might be more accurate to say the two different forms have "different syntactic affordances", in the linguist's terms, rather than different "meanings" as such.)